# Laravel "Trying to get property of non-object" Setting Array with Database Values

Tags: php, laravel

I'm Trying to solve this error i'm having with PHP, i'm not completely familiar with the Language, so it would be nice if you would help me out, I can't figure out this error.

I have this Code Here:

```
    public function index() {
    $counterino = ClientsJobs::all()->count();
    $MasterArray = array();
    /* Go Through All of the Records in the Client-Jobs Table and Resolve their columns to Desired Names */
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $counterino; $i++ ) {
        //Temporary Array for one Name-Resolved-Row of the Table.
        $tempArray = array(
            'id'          => ClientsJobs::find( $i )->id,              // id
            'client_name' => ClientsJobs::find( $i )->clients->fname , // get the first name ( based on fk )
            'job_name'    => ClientsJobs::find( $i )->jobs->name,      // get the name of the job ( based on fk )
            'wage'        => ClientsJobs::find( $i )->wage,            // wage for the job
            'productivity'=> ClientsJobs::find( $i )->producivity      // productivity level for the job
        );
        $MasterArray[] = $tempArray; //add the row
    }
    return $MasterArray;
}
```

This code changes the names of the of the Columns in the ClientsJobs Junction Table.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('clients-jobs', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned(); 
        $table->integer('client_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('clients');
        $table->integer('job_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('job_id')->references('id')->on('jobs');
        $table->decimal('wage', 4, 2);
        $table->decimal('productivity', 5, 2); // 0.00 - 100.00 (PERCENT)
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

The Jobs and Clients Table are very simple.

I am having the Error in the index() function I posted above, it says

'Trying to get property of non-object'

Starting on the Line

```
'client_name' => ClientsJobs::find( $i )->clients->fname,
```

It's also mad at me for the other parts of setting the array.

I have tested the individual functions I am using to set the array and they all work, fname should also return a string, I used dd() to get the value.

I have tried:

-Using FindorFail

-Setting the Array without the for loop and setting each element manually

-Dumping out multiple parts of the function to make sure it works( counterino, all of the functions for the array, .. )

My guess is that it has to do with the type-deduction of PHP, I actually only need a string array, but would still like to use the name mappings because I am going to be passing this a View I am using for some of my other stuff. The Code was actually working earlier, but I broke it somehow (adding a new record or running a composer update?) anyway, there's some serious voodoo going on.

Thanks in Advance for the help, I am working on this project for a Non-Profit Organization for free.

P.S. I am using Laravel 4.2, and Platform 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, this is a horrible practice:

```
    $tempArray = array(
        'id'          => ClientsJobs::find( $i )->id,              // id
        'client_name' => ClientsJobs::find( $i )->clients->fname , // get the first name ( based on fk )
        'job_name'    => ClientsJobs::find( $i )->jobs->name,      // get the name of the job ( based on fk )
        'wage'        => ClientsJobs::find( $i )->wage,            // wage for the job
        'productivity'=> ClientsJobs::find( $i )->producivity      // productivity level for the job
    );
```

By calling `ClientJobs::find($i)` multiple times, you are doing multiple times the same lookup - either to your DB, or to your cache layer if you have one configured.

Secondly, the answer to your question depends on your `ClientJobs` model. For your example to work, it needs:

- A valid `clients` relations, defined as follows:

  ```
   public function clients()
   {
       return $this->hasOne(...);
   }
  ```
- `clients` also needs to be a valid 1:1 **always existing** relation. i.e. there must always be one client. If there isn't, you are susceptible to the error you just got (as the `clients̀  magic would end up being null)

The same applies to `jobs`.

In every case, it is better to make sure everything is set first. Check using the following:

```
$clientJob = ClientJobs::find($i);
if (!$clientJob->clients || $clientJob->jobs) throw new \RangeException("No client or job defined for ClientJob $i");
```

And then catch the exception at whichever level you prefer.

## Best approach

```
public function index() {
  $masterArray = array();
  ClientsJobs::with('clients', 'jobs')->chunk(200, function($records) use (&$masterArray) {
      foreach ($records as $record) {
        $masterArray[] = array(
          'id'          => $record->id,              // id
          'client_name' => !empty($record->clients) ? $record->clients->fname : null,
          'job_name'    => !empty($record->jobs) ? $record->jobs->name : null,
          'wage'        => $record->wage,
          'productivity'=> $record->productivity,
        );
      }
  });
  return $MasterArray;
}
```

Comment: I'm using belongTo in my Client Model

Comment: I'm actually embarrassed of that find thing, thanks for pointing that out, I was using a findorfail at the beginning of the for loop and then just setting them, but I undid that

Comment: @user2837329: No problem. Also, `toArray` solves naught in this case. In practice, before just blinding going `$a->b->c->d`, unless you are **100% certain** that at least one object exists, double-check before use.

Comment: @user2837329: As for `belongsTo`, the same applies: are you certain that there is at least one client to each job? A single inconsistency in your DB could screw this up (Hint: on relational DBs where sharding is not needed, I tend to use FK constraints to enforce this)

Comment: Yes, there would only be 1 Person/Job per row, I'll try hasOne

Comment: @user2837329: `belongsTo` is correct in your case. I put that comment in there because I see way too many people sticking `hasMany` everywhere (which returns an array by default unless you use `first()` to only extract the first element). Still, the crux of your issue is: **before** you start traversing down the models, make sure that parent models **exist**.

Comment: @user2837329: Added a snippet that might be of some help. How to do it using chunking, eager-loading and while making sure that all entries are correct.

Comment: I get most of it, could you explain the with, the chunks, and the function $record

Comment: also is the & for reference?

Comment: @user2837329: `chunk` allows you to return and retrieve the records N by N. This is especially useful in order not to blow through the PHP max memory allocation. I do not know how many jobs you had, so I assumed this would be necessary. `function ($records) use (&$masterArray) {..}` is an IETF which is ran repeatedly by laravel, with $records being an array of the current set of rows. $masterArray is defined outside the scope of the IETF and is modifiable by reference (`&`) inside the IETF.

Comment: Also, I corrected my implementation slightly. Forgot that `chunk` calls using an array of rows, not row-by-row.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot, I'm amazed it worked, I sat here for a good hour trying to figure it out.

Comment: your solution is really nice, I like how fits it into place without having to use a loop I marked it as answer

Comment: @user2837329: Points to note - it's also more efficient than your initial when it comes to DB usage. It'll actually only do 3 queries per 200 records as opposed to the 401 you'd be doing with yours :-)

Comment: So I did this, noticed that it would only display the job once, So I check my clientsjobs model and it's set to hasOne, I change it to hasMany and it can't find the ->fname in the controller

Comment: @user2837329: This is a different issue. Your model may not be completely accurate. However, something else strikes me as odd. Why are you modelling the `clientjob`, which is a pivot, as a separate model? http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent may be helpful

Comment: My understanding of a model isn't complete, I think of it as a kind of representation of a database table. I'll look into the pivot table thing

Comment: @user2837329: A model is actually a representation of an entity. Your `ClientJob` is a logical link between a `job` and a `client`, right? It could be an entity of its own, but it's easier to represent it as a link. This link is called a pivot in a N:N relationship.

Comment: it also holds some data specific to the relationship too, the job productivity % is  based on how many pieces they can manufacture per hour, also the wage.

Comment: @user2837329: Pivots can have metadata associated to them! However, yes. If you judge it to be an entity of its own, consider it as an entity.

Answer (score 1):

Your Approach is very wrong
If you want to return an array you can do like this

```
$counterino = ClientsJobs::all()->toArray();
```

This will fetch all rows from the table and the toArray will convert the object into an array

Comment: I can do that, but I want to convert the Column client_id and job_id to the actual names of the job and the client. I'm unsure how to go about doing that because ClientsJobs::all() gives all of the rows and I want to do it in the controller

Comment: Do you have id=1 in your table.Also mysql queries are very expensive as it will load your server.

Comment: I have 1, 2 and 3 id's as sample data